# Deploy only specified files to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk allows for you to upload a git repository to your environment with a simple `eb deploy` command.

I know anything placed inside the .gitignore won't be deployed, but what about source files (sass, uncompressed scripts) I want to keep in the repository, but don't want uploaded on deployment.

Is there a way to only upload specific files?

---

**Follow-up**

Using Tal's answer below I was able to remove files on deploy with the following:

```
container_commands:
  remove_src_folder:
    command: "rm -rf public/src/"
```

Given this folder structure:

```
— .elasticbeanstalk
— .git
— public/
    — dist/
    — src/
    — index.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `eb deploy` than everything that's in git will be uploaded and deployed to the EB instance. That said, you can create an ebextension that removes those files after being deployed.
Here's an example for a file named `.ebextensions/cleanup.config`:

```
container_commands:
  remove_unneeded_file:
    rm $EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR/*.saas
```

this will run after the sources are copied to the EB instance, but before the web server is started.

Comment: I think your syntax needs a command before "rm $EB_APP..." but this solution works, thanks!

Comment: `Activity execution failed, because: rm: cannot remove`
What else is needed here to make this work?  I added `command:` before the last line already

Answer (score 6):

You can ignore files, which are in git using `.ebignore`. It will cause `.gitignore` to be ignored, so you may need some duplicate rules in both files.

It is documented here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore

Comment: And there's a good account [here](https://georgestocker.com/2015/06/01/deploy-untracked-files-with-git-and-elastic-beanstalk/)